# What do the first 4 letter stand for? Are they company name that made the tool or something else? ( From history )

Tags: meaning

[I was asked if the letters of the image are Japanese or not.](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/50607/what-language-is-this-in-my-sword-and-what-does-it-say)

I answered they must be Chinese since Japanese does not have the first letter.

What would the first 4 letters stand for?

Thank you for your help in advance!

[image]

Comment: See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61332/need-help-reading-old-hand-written-japanese/61333?r=SearchResults#61333 联 may not exist in Japanese now, but it was used as a shorthand form of 聯. Japanese no longer uses it, and replaced it with 連. Also, if you manage to get a clearer picture of the seal on the left, that may give more clues.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know even if I am a native Japanese. lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a clearer image (taken from http://iantiqueonline.ning.com/group/whadjafind/forum/topics/japanese-kanji-katana-samurai-sword-i-d-help?)

[image]

The text is verbatim:

[image]

> **張武傑** (seal of a person called 張武傑). Maybe this is supposed to suggest that 張武傑 was involved in the manufacturing.

联合刀具

> The name of a company called **联合 cutting tools**. 联合 should not be translated into *union* here, but treated as a proper noun. It might be in imitation of an American company originally called *Union Cutlery Co.*, now called [*Ka-Bar Knives., Inc*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ka-Bar); this company's Chinese name is frequently rendered as 联合刀具.

特殊鋼

> **Special steel**. According to [baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%89%B9%E6%AE%8A%E9%92%A2/949706), this is a non-standardised grade of steel, so it doesn't really mean anything.

---

In terms of orthography,「联」is normally **only** used in Mainland China, while「鋼」is normally **not** used in Mainland China. The structure of「联」, simplified from「聯」, is exactly analogous to the simplification of「關」to「関」.「関」is now normally only used in Japan.

Comment: Parts of this was also replicated on [the History SE question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/50607/what-language-is-this-and-what-does-it-say/50610). Apologies for the duplication ~